# How to have a dynamic time in debounce/throttle?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm trying to use something like this in Vue:

```
props(){
   debouncing: {type: Number, default: 0}
},
methods: {
    clicked: _.debounce(function() {
        this.$emit('click');
    }, this.debouncing),
}
```

However, this won't work when for example this is set: `debouncing = 4000`

Comment: `debounce` creates a new function with the time value baked in. You need to make a computed that returns a debounced function and have your method call that.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks! that was the tip I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @RoyJ's comment:

```
computed:{
    clicked(){
        return _.debounce(this.click, this.debouncing)
    }
},
methods:{
    click(){
       this.$emit('click');
    },
}
```